# JADE not rendering my property

Tags: express, pug

I use Express.js and Jade (1.11.0).
This is portion of my app.js:

```
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
```

This is how I send the object:

```
    var flattenMe = data[0]
    req.flash('success', { msg: 'Success! Got some Data.' });
    res.render('valuestream/vstreamhome', { vstream: flattenMe}

    //flattenMe is object with many properties
```

This is the Jade template:

```
#user
 if vstream
   h2 Description
   p.description= vstream.ProductData
 else
    h1 Description
    p.description No product Data
```

This is sample of flattenMe object (one object with one level properties):

```
flattenMe ={
  ProductData: "Some data",
  ProducDetails: "Product details data",
  ...
 }
```

What happens is the following:
First **if** works, and it sees there is an object vstream. Now I try to render vstream.ProductData property... and it does not work. And I have that property available.
If I dont send that object for rendering, than if goes to else, which is expected.

Comment: You should add a sample of the `flattenMe` object.

Comment: I have updated the answer.